# Multiple Wordpress Templates on One Page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Bear with me...

1. I am trying to create a simple Wordpress index template that allows users to edit copy using **custom fields**.
2. The index page is divided into 4 sections.
3. Each section has its own look and feel, as if it's its own page.

Here's what I was thinking:

1. Create each of the four sections as a Wordpress "page"
2. Apply a custom page template, with the HTML I'd like displayed, to each of the four pages.
3. Use custom fields to create any blocks of editable copy.
4. Display all of these pages on the index.php template.
5. Disable the visual editor on the pages and just show the custom fields.

Number 4 in the list above is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to get the pages (including their templates) onto the index. I'm also not sure if this is really the right way to be doing it. I also explored creating a custom object but didn't get to far. Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a templating engine, like Smarty, and then call templates as your conditional statements call for. http://www.smarty.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going to be able to display "pages" on one page, because that is not how Wordpress works. Each page is just that. A page.

Technically you CAN include 4 different iframes which load 4 different pages. And you can call them by their URL

The proper way to do this would be to include  four different POST TYPES on to your index page. And style them differently.

You can also do this by using CATEGORIES instead of custom post types. And just style each category differently.